# Reading bool values using a list

Tags: c#

Consider the following code:

```
public bool IsTwoInductions()
{
   List<Induction> inductionList = GetInduction();
   int? introTime = 0;
   foreach (var items in inductionList)
   {
     introTime = items.TotalTime;
   }
   if(introTime == 90)
   {
      return true;
   }
   else
   {
      return false;
   }
}
```

My list contains two records with `TotalTime == 90` and `TotalTime == 120`. Now when I output the value to console I get

> True
>
> True

But it should be `True` and `False`.. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: set breakpoints and step through the code - that way you will see exactly what it is doing.

Comment: @user1666620 I've done that and I can see `TotalTime` has the correct values

Comment: and do you see what the value of `introTime` is when it returns the values?

Comment: The question is: What do you really want? Currently your code only returns the LAST value of the list if it it is  ==90 or not. Wjhat exactly do you try to accomplish there? as you seem to get true and false but with a list it looks strange as it is unclear WHEN true and fals shall be returned. Thus when WHICH element has this value?

Comment: @Thomas I want to iterate the list and print out true and false depending on what `introTime` holds. If `introTime == 90` then `true` otherwise `false`

Comment: i don't see `TotalTime` in your code...

Comment: @code so going through the whole list and printing it out. That means then the return should not be made and instead the printing out there as else it is over after the frist list entry. I posted an answer according to the definition above that would iterate the whole array and give out true/false accordingly

Comment: @user1666620 Sorry I meant `introTime`

Comment: @Y.S it's a bad question where the actual requirements are only explicitly laid out in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly:

```
private void SomeMethod()
{
   List<int> inductionList = new List<int>() { 90, 120};
   int? introTime = 0;
   bool isEquelToNinety = false;
   foreach (var items in inductionList)
   {
      Console.WriteLine(isEquelToNinety=IsOK(items));
   }            
}

private bool IsOK(int? introTime)
{            
   if (introTime == 90)
   {
      return true;
   }
   else
   {
      return false;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public void IsTwoInductions()
{
   List<Induction> inductionList = GetInduction();
   int? introTime = 0;
   foreach (var items in inductionList)
   {
     introTime = items.TotalTime;

     if(introTime == 90)
     {
        Console.Write("true ");
     }
     else
     {
        Console.Write("false ");
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: That would iterate through the whole array and print out true, false accordding to what introtime for that entry is.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried this?

```
public bool IsTwoInductions()
{
   List<Induction> inductionList = GetInduction();
   bool isHaving90 = false;
   foreach (var items in inductionList)
   {
     introTime = items.TotalTime;
     if(introTime == 90)
     {
        isHaving90 = true;
        break;
     }
   }
   return isHaving90;
}
```

Comment: I tried your code and get the same results I'm afraid :/